# Angular 2 select with using default from seperate model

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I cannot find a way of setting the default or linking to another model while using `NgFor` over another model?

The model I'm trying to bind to is this:

```
"Bookings": {"dates":
[{"date":"3-10-2016","slot":"Full"},
{"date":"4-10-2016","slot":"Full"},
{"date":"5-10-2016","slot":"Afternoon"},
{"date":"6-10-2016","slot":"Morning"}]}
```

I have another model for the options:

```
lengthsObj = [
 {slot:'Full'},
 {slot:'Morning'},
 {slot:'Afternoon'}
];
```

I've tried every possible combination (with the model and value) I can think of with this:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of booking.dates">
 <select *ngIf="true" name="days" [(ngModel)]="date.slot" required>
    <option *ngFor="let length of lengthsObj" [value]="date.slot">
       {{length.slot}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

But I'm not getting a link to the model or any default values.

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N7rUed?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake by assigning data from `date.slot` to `ngValue`. Just change `ngValue` to `length.slot` in your plunker and it will work perfectly:

```
<select name="days" [(ngModel)]="date.slot" required>
    <option *ngFor="let length of lengthsObj" [ngValue]="length.slot">
        {{length.slot}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `length.slot` for `option` value as below :
Check [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TswCAaieTMaQ3xvkazDi)

```
<div *ngFor="let date of booking.dates">
  <select *ngIf="true" name="days" [(ngModel)]="date.slot" required>
    <option *ngFor="let length of lengthsObj" [value]="length.slot">
       {{length.slot}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```